# Why incomplete type (forward declared) size calculation cannot be postponed when using type as a field?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

In the following code:

```
class B;

struct A
{
   B* b; // <- why MUST be a pointer? Why size cannot be calculated later...?
}

struct B
{
   ...
}
```

As far as I understand, struct A must define b as B*, as the compiler cannot tell the size of B when calculating size of A.

What I do not understand, is why the compiler cannot postpone the calculation until it does find the full definition of B (as it was promised by the programmer by forwarding declare the class)

Comment: `struct B; struct A { B b; }; struct B { A a; };`

Comment: What is the full definition of `B` ***isn't*** available? What if `B` is an opaque data-type?

Comment: In some cases it probably could. But in some cases it couldn't. Either way, the language needs rules, and this is one of them.

Comment: *"as it was promised by the programmer by forwarding declare the class"* - A forward declaration **is not** a promise that the full definition will be visible later in the same TU. Opaque handles are one prominent example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine that you *could* actually define `A` as:

```
class B;

struct A {
   B b; // not a pointer
}
```

That is, `b` is a data member of *incomplete type* – the compiler doesn't know the size of `B` at this point.

Then, if `B` were defined as:

```
struct B {
   A a;
}
```

This would require infinite memory.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simply that C++ is designed to be compiled in a single pass through the source code (more or less); the goal is that the compiler doesn't have to postpone compiling something because there's not enough information at the point where it's defined.